# Apply GTK3 theme systemwide

Tags: gtk, themes, gtk3, xfce

#### Task / Problem:

I have a self-created gtk3-theme in `~/.local/share/themes/mytheme/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`. I would like to apply that style systemwide. How would I do that?

#### System:

- XUbuntu 19.04
- GTK version: 3.24

#### What I did / have:

- Prepare `~/.local/share/themes/mytheme/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`
- Created `~/.local/share/themes/mytheme/index.theme` with the following content:

```
Type=X-GNOME-Metatheme
Name=mytheme
Comment=mytheme
Encoding=UTF-8

[X-GNOME-Metatheme]
GtkTheme=mytheme
MetacityTheme=mytheme
ButtonLayout=:minimize,maximize,close
```

- Created `~/.local/share/themes/mytheme/gtk-3.0/gtk.gresource.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gresources>
    <gresource prefix='/usr/darktrick/gtk-3.0'>
        <file preprocess='to-pixdata'>images/icon_close.png</file>
        <file preprocess='to-pixdata'>images/icon_close_active.png</file>
        <file preprocess='to-pixdata'>images/icon_maximize.png</file>               
        <file preprocess='to-pixdata'>images/icon_minimize.png</file>       
        <file>gtk.css</file>
    </gresource>
</gresources>
```

- Tested css with GtkInspector (under `CSS`): worked fine
- Theme is available in GtkInspector under `Visual` to be applied manually.
- **edit:** I have chosen mytheme through the WindowManager dialog.

Comment: It's not quite clear: have you set it as your gtk theme via settings dialog?

Comment: Thanks. I added an edit: I've chosen the theme through the Window Manager dialog

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the answer.

Open "Settings Editor" -> channel "xsettings" -> Net -> ThemeName -> Type the folder name of the theme you'd like to have applied